# How can i compare current screen Edit text field value with shared preference value which is present in next screen?

Tags: android

```
public class Loginscreen extends Activity {
private EditText phonenumber,password;
private Button signin,joinus,supportus;
private TextView forgot_password;
String mobilenumber;
String passwordtxt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
    phonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_signin);
    joinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_joinus);
    supportus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_supportus);
    forgot_password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_remember_pawd);
   final String user = phonenumber.getText().toString();
    final String pass = password.getText().toString();



    signin.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //final Intent intent;
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final String pasword = pref.getString("pwd", null);
                    final String phnenumber = pref.getString("mobilenumber", null);
                    if ( pass == pasword && user == phnenumber &&  !pass.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(Loginscreen.this, "correct ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                               }
                                           else{
                        Toast.makeText(Loginscreen.this, "Incorrect Mobile number or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });
```

in above code how can i compare the shared preference value with current edit text value....i used shared preference in another page..

```
 @Override
   public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = null;
        try {
            jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject object = jsonobject.getJSONObject("data");
            String id = object.getString("_id");
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            pref.getString("key_name1",null);
        //final String encoded = pref.getString("key_name1",null);
        String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("_password");
        String mobilen = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("pwd",password);
        editor.putString("mobilenumber",mobilen);
        editor.putString("user_id",id);
        editor.commit();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the above code is present in another activity..how can i use that shared preference value in LoginScreen to compare both the values are equal are not

Comment: You can use, Bundle and putExtra to the Intent or use `Static` Variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals()` instead of `==`.
Change this part of the code:

```
if ( pass == pasword && user == phnenumber &&  !pass.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(Loginscreen.this, "correct ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else{
    Toast.makeText(Loginscreen.this, "Incorrect Mobile number or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

to:

```
if ( password.getText().toString().equals(password) && phonenumber.getText().toString().equals(phnenumber) &&  !pass.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(Loginscreen.this, "correct ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(Loginscreen.this, "Incorrect Mobile number or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with intent.
 in your first screen write below code on some button click.

```
Intent i=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("editTextvalue",editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

in your second screen write below code in onCreate()

```
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("editTextvalue");
```

campare this value with your sharedPreferences value.